# Why do we use $S^2$ while estimating the variance?

Tags: normal-distribution, sufficient-statistics, fisher-information

Sorry the title is a bit silly, but I currently confront a problem related to Fisher's information.

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ be of $N(\mu , \sigma^2 )$ distribution where $\mu$ is known, $U^2 := n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu )^2$, then $I_{U^2} (\sigma^2 ) > I_{S^2} (\sigma^2 )$.

In fact, $U^2$ is a sufficient statistic.
So, why do we often use $S^2$ to estimate the variance instead of using $U^2$?

Comment: Because we don't normally know $\mu$?

Comment: For normal data: When $\mu$ is unknown and estimated by $\bar X,$ then $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i(X_i-\bar X)^2$ has $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1),$ which is a bit hard to prove. When $\mu$ is known, then $U^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i(X_i-\mu)^2$ has $\frac{nU^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n),$ which is obvious.

Comment: So when we know $\mu$, we choose $U$ instead of $S$ ?